# is there a way to trigger a memory dump of oracle JVM at 80 or 90% usage?

Tags: java, jvm

The question says it all.  Without writing our own, is there a command line option to trigger a heap dump(jmap or whatever) when we hit some threshold.

It seems it is too late to dump the memory in certain cases where it fills up(it's too bad they don't always leave enough room for a heap dump to be possible by default).

Comment: https://blog.codecentric.de/en/2008/07/memory-analysis-part-1-obtaining-a-java-heapdump/

Comment: we had that option set on all our stuff for quite some time.....it doesn't work in this case or in a few cases actually like when gc is causing 99% cpu but isn't quite out of memory and at that point jmap is not working either so we need to trigger BEORE we get to 99% cpu and BEFORE 99% memory usage